# remove multiple new lines from a string in perl

Tags: string, perl, newline

I have a string like this:

```
city: London
Code: 123
address: 1, Napoleon
Phone: 123-123-1232
```

And all lines are in one string, and i want to print all information, but in one line with a separator.

i tried with this code:

```
$val =~ s/\n/\ /;
```

but nothing.

Comment: So, what is your code and how does it fail? Please [edit] your question and add the relevant code.

Comment: I do not have a code, I really do not know how to do this

Comment: I dont know if this edit help you, but i all i have...

Comment: @raulvarga  As you saw it now, it does help when you show us what you have :).  I suggest to always do that: post your code.  (Also, in addition to being able to help you out people will often also offer other improvements.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, you need the modifier `g`

See the behavior of this program, the second print shows you what you want.

You can see all the modifiers in [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) on perldoc.perl.org.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $val = <<'END';
city: London
Code: 123
address: 1, Napoleon
Phone: 123-123-1232
END

print $val;

$val =~ s/\n/ /g;

print $val;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the transliterate operator would also do the trick:

```
$val =~ tr/\n/ /;
```

Transliterate does a one-for-one mapping of characters, which means it's not as multi-purpose, but it does nicely for things like this.  It can also do cool things like:

```
$val =~ tr/\n/ /s;
```

Where the "s" suffix means take any number of newline characters and replace them with a single space, in the event you have blank spaces -- like if the "address line 2" is optional and might be blank.